# Looking for an online version of Archimedes' "The Method" (in Greek)

Tags: calculus, archimedes

To me, one of the most exciting mathematical achievements of antiquity is Archimedes' [The Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Method_of_Mechanical_Theorems). It is crazy to think that, had it not been for its miraculous recovery in the early 20th century, it would perhaps have been lost forever. In translation, it can be found online [here](http://wilbourhall.org/index.html#archimedes). The original text, however, seems as hard to find as ever, at least in terms of on-line availability. While I can find the Greek version of most of his other works online, I can't find it for the "Method". Can someone help me?

Comment: If you have unrivalled patience and a keen eye, you can view images of the entire Palimpsest at http://www.archimedespalimpsest.net

Comment: @NickR: to be perfectly honest, I have neither. But it might be worth a try if there aren't any other options.

Comment: Heiberg included the full text when he announced his discovery: http://www.jstor.org/stable/4473078

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was answered by Viktor Blasjo in the comments: the Greek text is included in [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/4473078) article by Heiberg.